# Setting and clearing bits in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have some trouble with a C program that does some bit manipulation. In the program, I use an unsigned long long int variable to represent a 64 bit map, each bit representing a position on the map. I need to be able to update these bits (positions) i.e. setting or clearing a bit.
To clear and set a bit, I do (0 is the least significant position):

```
map &= ~(1 << pos) // clear bit in position 'pos'
map |= (1 << pos) // set bit in position 'pos'
```

The problem is that when i perform these operations, all the bits in the map which are to the left of `pos` get set to 0 (while I want only the bit in position `pos` to change).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `1ULL` to ensure the mask is the correct size.

Comment: This has been asked before, several times. The problem is the type of the `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that those shifts are done using the type `int`, which on all modern 64-bit systems are still 32 bits. You need to use the same type as `map`, i.e. `unsigned long long`:

```
1ull << pos
```

Note the `ull` which tells the compiler that the `1` is not an `int` but an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it was something with the data types, but I didn't know how to make the shifts with the same type as the map.